# How to create a Sidebar form in delphi

Tags: delphi

How can I create a Sidebar form in delphi.

I try the `ScreenSnap` and `Align` properties but I need that the form stay visible even if the user maximize other forms, without been on top. Just like the windows sidebar do.

**Update**: From the comments: if a window is maximized, it maximizes next to the window, not in front of or behind.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is your form to dock on the side of the screen and effectively reduce the desktop size in the same way that the task bar and other sidebars do.  So if a window is maximized it maximizes next too your window, not in front of or behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an *AppBar*. Begin your research with the [`ShAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108.aspx) API function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Windows API function to force your application to stay on top:

```
SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I Already try setting the FormStyle property to fsStayOnTop (I think that make the same as the code you posted). But i need that the form stay visible without been on top of others like the taskbar on windows or the sidebar in vista.

Comment: @Marioh: No, the API function I mentioned is NOT the same as setting the FormStyle to fsStayOnTop.  As you have discovered, setting the FormStyle doesn't work.  Calling the API function DOES work.

Comment: @Kluge: He is looking for docking, not stay on top.  His question was unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Jim.  I thought this question sounded too easy.